# How to run browserify without ecmascript-6 transpilation?

Tags: ecmascript-6, browserify, babelify

Recently I stumbled upon a library for `nodejs`, that I want to use in a frontend project. Because the whole project is developed in ES6, the library should not be transpiled (we only develop for browsers, supporting es6). Of course, I could "browserify" manually, but because it can be a reoccurring task, I would like to use `browserify` without `babelify` or any es6 transpilation process.
If transpilation is needed later on, I'd integrate it into the whole build process, but not beforehand.

Is there any option to `browserify` to omit es6 to ecmascript-5.1 transpilation?

Comment: What problems did you meet and what did make you think that you can't? Browserify doesn't do transpilation itself. That's why there are plugins like Babelify.

Comment: browserify works fine, but the output is ecmascript-5.1 rather than es6. I want to disable the babelify process.

Comment: Then don't install Babelify and don't use it in configuration or anywhere else. Again, Browserify doesn't do transpilation by default.

Comment: No, that's why I'm asking here. browserify  cli  quits, when babelify isn't installed. I want to know the command line option to disable transpilation plugin.

Comment: Please, update the question with clear description of what you're doing and other details that could solve the issue, which packages you installed, including their versions. The problem that you imply and expect to affect everyone just doesn't exist. Browserify [does not have Babelify among its dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) and cannot physically transpile anything when Babelify is not explicitly used. I run `browserify ./example.js` and can clearly see that it is still ES6, just browserified.

Comment: It turned out that the library, I was wanting to browserify, had some options to browserify in it's `package.json`, which "magically" enabled the babelify plugin. Shall I post this as an answer or still modify the question?

Comment: I'd suggest to post this as an answer since this may help somebody with such problem.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `browserify` does not do any transpilation process, if no plugins are enabled. It turned out, that the library I wanted  `browserify`, passed some options to browserify in its `package.json`:

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": [ [ "babelify", { "presets": "es2015" } ] ]
}
```

this caused browserify to use the babelify plugin by default.